Geometry Nodes (4.1): How to make "hills" connect smoothly to flat terrain
My nodetree creates random hilly terrain on faces with the green material. Hills close to the border of the material get cut off. How can i force the hills to connect smoothly to the border instead of ending "in the air"?



you can use this node tree here:

to get this:
https://github.com/luckychris/blender_gifs/blob/main/flat%20at%20edges.gif
sorry for the gif-link, but since the "improvement" of the pic upload of SE, gif uploading doesn't work at all for me in the last days.
Essentially first i save the old position (flat), then i separate the border by using the face count == 3 (this works because you have nice quad faces, this won't work with tris or bad geometry), and then using the proximity to that border for mixing the factor of the old and the new position. The map range is for fine-tuning the result. Of course you can also use additionally or instead a float curve for even more detail fine tuning.

Thats almost perfect. Using "Edge Neighours = 1" is more intuitive to select the border of areas though, no worries about bad geometry like that. (gotta switch seperate geometry and geometry proximity to "edges" mode then)

that's actually a great idea!
